# run multiple apps on different ports in nodejs express framework

Tags: node.js, express

I am running an application using node.js express framework on port 3000 (http://localhost:3000) in my windows machine. Also i want to run another(second) application on different port say like 3005 or 8080 etc. In my first application i didn't specified any port number and i believe expressjs by default runs on port 3000. But in second app i mentioned port number **app.listen(8080)** in my app.js. When i tried to start second application am getting **port 3000 is already in use** error. So i stopped first appliction and then only i can run second application and also it is running on both 3000 and 8080 ports. I didn't understand why it is still running on 3000 still i specified port 8080 number in app.js.

Could any one help to run both application on different ports in same instance

Thanks

Comment: try to find which process/service/app is running on port 3000 by any means...by writing commands in your windows terminal.Like in windows command prompt type : netstat -n...if you din't find (port number with process) then try some other command that will give you ( port number with process ) info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i believe expressjs by default runs on port 3000

It's true, but you can change it.

I think you run express default boilerplate app.
In this case you should update line `var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');` in `bin/www`.

Comment: @Farkan Basaran: can we override the same in app.js without changing in www file?

Comment: Yes, of course! You should add this line `process.env.PORT = 8080;` before `module.exports = app;` in `app.js` file.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [express generator](http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html) also check the www file in the bin folder, which probably contains a part similier to this:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

Change the '3000' part to the port you desire and it should run as intended.

Answer (score 2):

Lastly to change port use "PORT=4000 node app/app.js" in cmd line.
Port no can be changed to any other port no. 5000,6000 etc ...

Comment: Sorry for inadvertently downvoting your answer (maybe my hand on the touchpad?). If I try to undo, I get the message "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited." Could you edit your answer (maybe three dots after etc) so that I can undo the downvote? I'm really sorry, especially because it seems to be your first post on SO.

Answer (score 1):

It worked after changing port number in www file. www file is located in bin folder that was created during enviornment setup.